# Javascript : Join within same JS object on different keys based on values

Tags: javascript, join, lodash

In my AngularJS 1.3 project, I am trying to join objects with given keys and merged. Consider below object (for better understanding, consider keys as table columns):

```
var json = {
    "filteredTask": [{
        "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "c@c",
        "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "50000",
        "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "30000",
        "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"
    }, {
        "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "b@b",
        "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "25000",
        "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
        "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "QA"
    }, {
        "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "a@a",
        "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "22000",
        "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
        "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"
    }, {
        "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "c@c",
        "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Admin",
        "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "HR"
    }, {
        "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "b@b",
        "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Non Technical",
        "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "QA"
    }, {
        "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "a@a",
        "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Technical",
        "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "Developer"
    }],
    "filter": {
        "joinField": [{
            "formField": {
                "new_key": "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776"
            },
            "withFormField": {
                "new_key": "Email_1202_1_1554368387884"
            }
        }, {
            "formField": {
                "new_key": "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751"
            },
            "withFormField": {
                "new_key": "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Kindly note, `filteredTask` contains all the data and `filter` contains joining field key information.

Now, I want to perform join just like SQL on JSON. For example, join on two keys `Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776` and `Email_1202_1_1554368387884` (email matching like a@a, b@b & c@c), result should be as below as combined.

```
[{
    "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "c@c",
    "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "50000",
    "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "30000",
    "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer",
    "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "c@c",
    "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Admin",
    "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "HR"
}, {
    "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "b@b",
    "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "25000",
    "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
    "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "QA",
    "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "b@b",
    "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Non Technical",
    "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "QA"
}, {
    "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "a@a",
    "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "22000",
    "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
    "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer",
    "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "a@a",
    "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Technical",
    "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "Developer"
}]
```

Now, if I perform two join like `Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776` with `Email_1202_1_1554368387884` (email) and `Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751` with `Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611` (designation), then result should be something like below, considering email and designation both match :

```
[{
    "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "b@b",
    "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "25000",
    "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
    "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "QA",
    "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "b@b",
    "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Non Technical",
    "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "QA"
}, {
    "Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "a@a",
    "Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "22000",
    "Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000",
    "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer",
    "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "a@a",
    "Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Technical",
    "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "Developer"
}]
```

I have tried [lodash library](https://lodash.com) utilities for this.

```
angular.forEach(json.filter.joinField, function (jField) {
    var obj1 = _.filter(json.filteredTask, function (o1) {
        return o1[jField.formField.new_key];
    });

    var obj2 = _.filter(json.filteredTask, function (o2) {
        return o2[jField.withFormField.new_key];
    });

    // for intersaction data
    var result = _.intersectionWith(_.cloneDeep(obj1), obj2, function (x, y) {
        //Improvement needed here: when I print, it shows different keys and values and generated output differently.
        return x[jField.formField.new_key] === y[jField.withFormField.new_key] && _.assign(x, y);
    });

    json.filteredTask = result;
});
console.log(json);
```

Let me know if we can achieve this any other way or this one can be improved.

Comment: This is not about JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: Removed tag as suggested.

Comment: Just be aware that talking about JSON in your question is misleading: it is about JavaScript objects. JSON is text

Comment: What is "filter" about in your data? Is it relevant for the question?

Comment: If this doesn't work, give a [mcve]. If it does work, what improvement are you looking for?

Comment: `filter` is the keys object where join fields information are mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you could take:

1. Extract the join conditions from the "joinField" data so you get simple [a, b] pairs
2. For each row determine on which side of the join it is: if the left field of the first join condition is present in the row, it is on the left.
3. Create a composite key from the fields listed in the join conditions -- on the side that the record is on
4. Group the rows by their composite key: there will be groups for the left side and for the right side
5. Join rows from the left group and right group for the same key: this is a Cartesian product
6. Concatenate all these results

Here is how you could do that in ES2018:

```js
function join(obj) {
    // Extract join conditions
    const keys = obj.filter.joinField.map(pair => 
                     [pair.withFormField.new_key, pair.formField.new_key]);
    const grouped = [new Map, new Map]; // groups for left & right side
    const result = [];
    // Put rows in buckets based on their join fields
    for (const row of obj.filteredTask) {
        // Determine which "side" of the join this row is on
        let side = +(keys[0][1] in row);
        // Create single key value:
        let key = JSON.stringify(keys.map(pair => row[pair[side]]));
        if (!grouped[side].has(key)) grouped[side].set(key, []);
        grouped[side].get(key).push(row);
    }
    // Perform the join
    for (const [key, rows1] of grouped[0]) {
        // pick up rows from the other side that share the same key (intersection)
        const rows2 = grouped[1].get(key);
        if (!rows2) continue;
        for (const row1 of rows1) {
            for (const row2 of rows2) result.push({...row1, ...row2});
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var data = {"filteredTask": [{"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "c@c","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "50000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "30000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"}, {"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "b@b","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "25000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "QA"}, {"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "a@a","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "22000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "c@c","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Admin","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "HR"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "b@b","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Non Technical","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "QA"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "a@a","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Technical","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "Developer"}],"filter": {"joinField": [{"formField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776"},"withFormField": {"new_key": "Email_1202_1_1554368387884"}}, {"formField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751"},"withFormField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611"}}]}};

const result = join(data);

console.log(result);
```

In ES5:

```js
function join(obj) {
    // Extract join conditions
    var keys = obj.filter.joinField.map(pair => 
                     [pair.withFormField.new_key, pair.formField.new_key]);
    var grouped = [{}, {}]; // groups for left & right side
    var result = [];
    // Put rows in buckets based on their join fields
    obj.filteredTask.forEach(function (row) {
        // Determine which "side" of the join this row is on
        var side = +(keys[0][1] in row);
        // Create single key value:
        var key = JSON.stringify(keys.map(function (pair) {
            return row[pair[side]];
        }));
        if (!grouped[side][key]) grouped[side][key] = [];
        grouped[side][key].push(row);
    });
    // Perform the join
    for (var key in grouped[0]) {
        var rows1 = grouped[0][key];
        // pick up rows from the other side that share the same key (intersection)
        var rows2 = grouped[1][key];
        if (!rows2) continue;
        rows1.forEach(function (row1) {
            rows2.forEach(function (row2) {
                result.push(Object.assign({}, row1, row2)); 
            });
        });
    }
    return result;
}

var data = {"filteredTask": [{"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "c@c","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "50000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "30000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"}, {"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "b@b","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "25000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "QA"}, {"Email_1202_1_1554368387884": "a@a","Number_1202_2_1554368395451": "22000","Number_1202_3_1554368408148": "20000","Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611": "Developer"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "c@c","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Admin","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "HR"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "b@b","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Non Technical","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "QA"}, {"Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776": "a@a","Text_Field_1202_2_1554367980023": "Technical","Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751": "Developer"}],"filter": {"joinField": [{"formField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_1_1554367796776"},"withFormField": {"new_key": "Email_1202_1_1554368387884"}}, {"formField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_3_1554367980751"},"withFormField": {"new_key": "Text_Field_1202_4_1554368416611"}}]}};

var result = join(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, that looks similar to what I want. However, I am not using `ES6 JavaScript`, since my project is in older AngularJS 1.3 version where node js is not used. Can we achieve this in older version of Javascript?

Comment: I added an ES5 version. Is that old enough? If not you might have a problem with `Object.assign`. Let me know and I'll add an alternative for that as well.